# Properties File Loading Using Static Code in Class

Tags: java

I have a 'PropertiesUtil' class for reading properties from a configuration file. The code of the class is given below:

```
public class PropertiesUtil {

  public static Properties prop;
  public static String databaseConnectivityString;
  public static String databaseUserName;
  public static String databaseUserPassword;

  static {
      try {
          prop.load(new FileReader(new File("config.prop")));
          databaseConnectivityString = prop.getProperty("databaseConnectivityString");
          databaseUserName = prop.getProperty("databaseUserName");
          databaseUserPassword = prop.getProperty("databaseUserPassword");
      } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException ex) {
          LoggerUtil.getLogger().severe("Problem loading or Reading Configuration file");
      }
  }
}
```

when I call the following code from another class 'Test' with a main method I get a NullPointerException. The code of the 'Test' Class is given below. Kindly help me troubleshoot.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
      System.out.println(PropertiesUtil.databaseUserName);
  }
}
```

Comment: check congig.pop is available in current class path or not ..then match the properties key with property name that you provided in your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize your field right away.

```
public static Properties prop = new Properties();
```

otherwise the field remains `null` and dereferencing it

```
prop.load(new FileReader(new File("config.prop")));
```

causes a `NullPointerException`.